# Dynamically Display Menu Nodes and their children DNN

Tags: menu, dotnetnuke, html-encode, ascx

I already have it hard coded in the skin file using the dnn:menu that selects specific nodes, but it looks like id have to create several additional skins to differentiate NodeSelectors between rootMenu items (4 of them).

Is there a way, using the same skin file on any given page, that can I tell which rootMenu item I am on, loop thru it's first level of child pages as tabs, while listing their children in an expandable accordion part as it goes?

Uhh...the simpler the better.

Using

```
<ddr:MENU menustyle="Accordion" runat="server" /></dnn:MENU>
```

and this Accordian.XSLT showed promise but expanding didnt work.

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="html"/>
 <xsl:param name="ControlID" />
 <xsl:param name="Options" />
 <xsl:param name="CSSClass" />
  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="root" />
  </xsl:template>
  
   <xsl:template match="root/node">
   <xsl:if test="@breadcrumb = 1 and count(descendant::node) > 0">

   <script type="text/javascript">
       jQuery(function($) {
         var options = { initialIndex: -1 };
         $.extend(options, { <xsl:apply-templates select="node" mode="breadcrumb" /> }, <xsl:value-of select="$Options" />);
       $("#<xsl:value-of select="$ControlID" />").tabs(".toolsaccordion div.pane", options);
    });
   </script>
   <div id="{$ControlID}" class="toolsaccordion">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node" />
   </div>
  </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="node" mode="breadcrumb">
    <xsl:if test="@breadcrumb = 1">initialIndex: <xsl:value-of select="position() - 1" /></xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="node">
  <h3>
   
    <xsl:value-of select="@text" />
   
  </h3>
  <div class="pane">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node" mode="sub">
    <xsl:with-param name="level" select="0" />
   </xsl:apply-templates>
  </div>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="node" mode="sub">
  <xsl:param name="level" />
  <xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="@enabled = 0">
    <div>
     <xsl:call-template name="indent">
      <xsl:with-param name="level" select="$level" />
     </xsl:call-template>
     <xsl:value-of select="@text" />
    </div>
   </xsl:when>
   <xsl:otherwise>
    <a style="display:block" href="{@url}">
     <xsl:call-template name="indent">
      <xsl:with-param name="level" select="$level" />
     </xsl:call-template>
     <xsl:value-of select="@text" />
    </a>
   </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="node" mode="sub">
   <xsl:with-param name="level" select="$level + 1" />
  </xsl:apply-templates>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template name="indent">
  <xsl:param name="level" />
  <xsl:if test="$level &gt; 0">
   &#160;&#160;<xsl:call-template name="indent">
    <xsl:with-param name="level" select="$level - 1" />
   </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

```html
Here is the menudef.xml




<? xml version = "1.0"
encoding = "utf-8" ?>
  < manifest >
  < template > Accordion.xslt < /template>
  <scripts>
    <script jsObject="jQuery" / >
  < script jsObject = "jQuery.tools.tabs" > http: //www.itdraws.com/js/flowplayer.org-1.1.2-jquery.tools.min.js</script>
  < /scripts>
  <stylesheets>
    <stylesheet>[MANIFEST]/tabs - accordion.css < /stylesheet>
  </stylesheets >
  < defaultClientOptions >
  < clientOption name = "tabs"
type = "string"
value = "h3" / >
  < clientOption name = "effect"
type = "string"
value = "slide" / >
  < clientOption name = "event"
type = "string"
value = "onclick" / >
  < /defaultClientOptions>
</manifest >
```

Comment: This is definitely possible, I'll see if I can't find some example code for this.

Comment: that would be super great Chris, thanks!

Comment: at the very least i would consider conditional code that writes/doesn't write blocks of menu code.

Comment: This works for a a specific page:

 <% if (PortalSettings.ActiveTab.TabName.Equals("Tab Name")) { %> 0,1 <%= Server.HtmlEncode(PortalSettings.ActiveTab.TabName) %> <% } else { %> 2 and up? <%= Server.HtmlEncode(PortalSettings.ActiveTab.TabName) %> <% } %> 


but what i need to do is at least is identify the +0 parent in the conditional statement. This is my head banging against the wall :P –

Comment: Sorry Gomez, I haven't had a chance to get this together yet.

Comment: I was able to use the ddrmenu to write the root menu  items and children but the accordion/expanding functionality is not working. From the looks of it the jquery is expired, ive found it online elsewhere so im gonna try to dowload that and point to it locally. Sheesh!!! I post the result after I lunch it.

Comment: Welp...no dice. Saw a video tutorial that looked promising but used a depreciated versionof jquery, just doesnt work. Any assist with this would be super great.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it might be easier to use a Razor template to work in the conditional stuff.

(You could take a look at the MegaMenu template as an example.)

Comment: im not exactly sure how to do that as accordion

Answer (score 0):

A very short answer is that you would generate the HTML (using whatever template you are using) in "accordion format" and then use jquery.accordion to do the accordion work.

Take a look at the jquery documentation for examples of the HTML structure that you need to generate.

Comment: I brought in the jquery

`<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="JQUERY" Src="~/Admin/Skins/jQuery.ascx" %>`

Set this 
`
$(function() {
    $( "#lobNavs" ).accordion({
    collapsible: true,
        heightStyle: "content",
active: curNode
    });
  });
`

and used this menu code.

`<dnn:MENU menustyle="ULTokens" id="Boo" runat="server" NodeSelector="+0" /></dnn:MENU>`

and styled is accordingly. Gave me what i needed, kinda....

Comment: I still need to be able to show/not show content based on the root parent. Which was an important part of what i need to include on the skin/ascx file. I have this but it only works on a single page(which is the parent) 

`<% if (PortalSettings.ActiveTab.TabName.Equals("Wealth Management")) { %>`

This works too, but again, only for the single page

`<% if (DotNetNuke.Entities.Portals.PortalController.GetCurrentPortalSettings().ActiveTab.ParentId.Equals(480)) { %>`

Answer (score 0):

I have several answers here that work.

The DNN ascx if/else() statements look like this:

```
<% if (singleConditionExample)  { %>
    alert("Hello World");

<% } else if (multipleConditionsHere() || multipleConditionsHere() && multipleConditionsHere())   { %>    // standard operators. you get the idea.
    alert("elseifConditionsHere");

<% } else { %>
    alert("Else Msg");

<% } %>
```

As for getting DNN page tabId, tabName, ParentId, these went into the if() conditions.

//CURRENT PAGE ROOT PARENT FROM DNN BREADCRUB

`PortalSettings.ActiveTab.BreadCrumbs[0]`

//CURRENT DNN PAGE NAME

`PortalSettings.ActiveTab.TabName.Equals("Wealth Management")`

//CURRENT DNN PAGE ID NUMBER

`<%=PortalSettings.ActiveTab.TabID %>`

//CURRENT DNN PAGE PARENT ID

`DotNetNuke.Entities.Portals.PortalController.GetCurrentPortalSettings().ActiveTab.ParentId.Equals(480)`

If you want to write them to the page:

`<%=PortalSettings.ActiveTab.BreadCrumbs(0).FullUrl%>`

I'm certain there is more to learn and when I do learn more, as it relates to getting DNN page id, breadbrumbs, etc...i will update this answer.

Cheers!